# Tooltip outside working in highcharts but not in highstock

Tags: highcharts

I'm having issues with tooltip outside in highstock, but it works perfectly fine in highcharts

I checked the docs & there doesn't seem to be a difference in config for tooltip for highstock vs highcharts.

Please find a highcharts jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gv5szaeu/

relevant snippet

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {

chart: {
    type: 'column',
    borderWidth: 1
},

  tooltip: {
      outside: true,
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
       var s =  '<table><tr><td>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br></td></tr></table>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       return s;
       },
  },
});
```

And highstock:
https://jsfiddle.net/h45o2xwv/4

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    tooltip: {
      outside: true,
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
       var s =  '<table><tr><td>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br></td></tr></table>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       s += '<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>';
       return s;
       },
  },
 });
```

Expected: tooltip: outside should work the same in both

Actual: highstock tooltip not displaying at all; highcharts tooltip displaying correctly outside of chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Highstock a `split` option is enabled by default, so you need to disable it:

```
tooltip: {
    split: true,
    ...
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/46ywhxou/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.split

Comment: This does seem to fix it for my trivial example, but I don't understand why this impacts the outside behavior.
In my real life example, i have multiple points which i then aggregate with a custom formatter manually. If i turn of split, i wouldn't be able to do this.
Nonetheless, the behavior is the same with the split functionality for highcharts & highstocks so I will accept the answer

Comment: Hi ExaSephiroth, Here you can find an information in the code that `outside` option is not supported with `split`: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/Tooltip.js#L176

Comment: oh my god - thank you! i searched for hours ....